# Loading large file (25k entries) into dict is slow in Python?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, io

I have a file which has about 25000 lines, and it's a s19 format file.

each line is like: S214 **780010** ***00802000000010000000000A508CC78C*** 7A

There are no spaces in the actual file, the first part `780010` is the address of this line, and I want it to be a dict's key value, and I want the data part ***00802000000010000000000A508CC78C*** be the value of this key. I wrote my code like this:

```
def __init__(self,filename):
    infile = file(filename,'r')
    self.all_lines = infile.readlines()
    self.dict_by_address = {}

    for i in range(0, self.get_line_number()):
        self.dict_by_address[self.get_address_of_line(i)] = self.get_data_of_line(i)

    infile.close()
```

get_address_of_line() and get_data_of_line() are all simply string slicing functions. get_line_number() iterates over self.all_lines and returns an int

problem is, the init process takes me over 1 min, is the way I construct the dict wrong or python just need so long to do this?

And by the way, I'm new to python:) maybe the code looks more C/C++ like, any advice of how to program like python is appreciated:)

Comment: How big is the file and how did you wrote the other functions? BTW your code is not even slightly pythonic...

Comment: The problem is that you're loading the entire file into memory before putting it inside the dictionary.

Comment: Although the answers so far have nice suggestions for your code, none of them offers an explanation on why is it taking that long - reading 30000 lines 160 charaters long and making a dict out of them should take less than 1 second. Your methods, even though you say "are simply making this" should be very wrong. Please, post all your code.

Comment: @Wes: no way reading a 25000 line text file into memory on any 256MB+ machine would make a speed difference.

Comment: I agree with @jsbueno: there's no way this should take 1 min.  If I had to guess, I'd say that one of the `.get_*` methods was doing its own loop up to i for some reason so the total time was O(N^2).

Comment: I just timed my code, and something like his code, and both took well under a second for a 25000 line text file.  All I can guess is what @DSM said: his slicing functions might be doing something weird, since we don't have source for them and they are the only mystery.  My code handled the 25000 line text file in .015 seconds; his code (with slicing functions I wrote) took only .03 seconds, almost exactly half the speed but nowhere near a minute.

Comment: the origin code stores every line in `self.all_lines`, and get* is returning something like `self.all_lines[line_no][4:10]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code should be tremendously faster than what you have now.  EDIT: As @sth pointed out, this doesn't work because there are no spaces in the actual file.  I'll add a corrected version at the end.

```
def __init__(self,filename):
    self.dict_by_address = {}

    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            _, key, value, _ = line.split()
            self.dict_by_address[key] = value
```

Some comments:

- Best practice in Python is to use a `with` statement, unless you are using an old Python that doesn't have it.
- Best practice is to use `open()` rather than `file()`; I don't think Python 3.x even has `file()`.
- You can use the open file object as an iterator, and when you iterate it you get one line from the input.  This is better than calling the `.readlines()` method, which slurps all the data into a list; then you use the data one time and delete the list.  Since the input file is large, that means you are probably causing swapping to virtual memory, which is always slow.  This version avoids building and deleting the giant list.
- Then, having created a giant list of input lines, you use `range()` to make a big list of integers.  Again it wastes time and memory to build a list, use it once, then delete the list.  You can avoid this overhead by using `xrange()` but even better is just to build the dictionary as you go, as part of the same loop that is reading lines from the file.
- It might be better to use your special slicing functions to pull out the "address" and "data" fields, but if the input is regular (always follows the pattern of your example) you can just do what I showed here.  `line.split()` splits the line on white space, giving a list of four strings.  Then we unpack it into four variables using "destructuring assignment".  Since we only want to save two of the values, I used the variable name `_` (a single underscore) for the other two.  That's not really a language feature, but it is an idiom in the Python community: when you have data you don't care about you can assign it to `_`.  This line will raise an exception if there are ever any number of values other than 4, so if it is possible to have blank lines or comment lines or whatever, you should add checks and handle the error (at least wrap that line in a `try:`/`except`).

EDIT: corrected version:

```
def __init__(self,filename):
    self.dict_by_address = {}

    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            key = extract_address(line) 
            value = extract_data(line)
            self.dict_by_address[key] = value
```

Comment: "There are no spaces in the actual file"

Answer (score 9):

How about something like this? (I made a test file with just a line `S21478001000802000000010000000000A508CC78C7A` so you might have to adjust the slicing.)

```
>>> with open('test.test') as f:
...     dict_by_address = {line[4:10]:line[10:-3] for line in f}
... 
>>> dict_by_address
{'780010': '00802000000010000000000A508CC78C'}
```

Comment: Even better still!  If all you are doing is build a `dict`, then just do it!