# Python 2.7 - find and replace from text file, using dictionary, to new text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am newbie to programming, and have been studying python in my spare time for the past few months. I decided I was going to try and create a little script that converts American spellings to English spellings in a text file.

I have been trying all sorts of things for the past 5 hours, but eventually came up with something that got me somewhat closer to my goal, but not quite there!

```
#imported dictionary contains 1800 english:american spelling key:value pairs. 
from english_american_dictionary import dict


def replace_all(text, dict):
    for english, american in dict.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(american, english)
    return text


my_text = open('test_file.txt', 'r')

for line in my_text:
    new_line = replace_all(line, dict)
    output = open('output_test_file.txt', 'a')
    print >> output, new_line

output.close()
```

I am sure there is a considerably better way to go about things, but for this script,here are the issues I am having:

- In the output file the lines are written on every other line, with a line break between, but the original test_file.txt does not have this. Contents of test_file.txt shown at bottom of this page
- Only the first instance of an American spelling in a line gets converted to English.
- I didn't really want to open output file in append mode, but couldn't figure out 'r' in this code structure.

Any help appreciated for this eager newb!

The contents of the test_file.txt are:

```
I am sample file.
I contain an english spelling: colour.
3 american spellings on 1 line: color, analyze, utilize.
1 american spelling on 1 line: familiarize.
```

Comment: Just a note: It's a very bad idea to use `dict` as the name of a variable, since that shadows the name of the builtin dictionary type. This may cause your code to break in confusing ways if you are not careful.

Comment: thanks for that tip, will not use 'dict' as a variable here on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The extra blank line you are seeing is because you are using `print` to write out a line that already includes a newline character at the end. Since `print` writes its own newline too, your output becomes double spaced. An easy fix is to use `outfile.write(new_line)` instead.

As for the file modes, the issue is that you're opening the output file over and over. You should just open it once, at the start. Its usually a good idea to use `with` statements to handle opening files, since they'll take care of closing them for you when you're done with them.

I don't undestand your other issue, with only some of the replacements happening. Is your dictionary missing the spellings for `'analyze'` and `'utilize'`?

One suggestion I'd make is to not do your replacements line by line. You can read the whole file in at once with `file.read()` and then work on it as a single unit. This will probably be faster, since it won't need to loop as often over the items in your spelling dictionary (just once, rather than once per line):

```
with open('test_file.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    text = in_file.read()

with open('output_test_file.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    out_file.write(replace_all(text, spelling_dict))
```

Edit:

To make your code correctly handle words that contain other words (like "entire" containing "tire"), you probably need to abandon the simple `str.replace` approach in favor of regular expressions.

Here's a quickly thrown together solution that uses `re.sub`, given a dictionary of spelling changes from American to British English (that is, in the reverse order of your current dictionary):

```
import re

#from english_american_dictionary import ame_to_bre_spellings
ame_to_bre_spellings = {'tire':'tyre', 'color':'colour', 'utilize':'utilise'}

def replacer_factory(spelling_dict):
    def replacer(match):
        word = match.group()
        return spelling_dict.get(word, word)
    return replacer

def ame_to_bre(text):
    pattern = r'\b\w+\b'  # this pattern matches whole words only
    replacer = replacer_factory(ame_to_bre_spellings)
    return re.sub(pattern, replacer, text)

def main():
    #with open('test_file.txt') as in_file:
    #    text = in_file.read()
    text = 'foo color, entire, utilize'

    #with open('output_test_file.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    #    out_file.write(ame_to_bre(text))
    print(ame_to_bre(text))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

One nice thing about this code structure is that you can easily convert from British English spellings back to American English ones, if you pass a dictionary in the other order to the `replacer_factory` function.

Comment: I appreciate all the answers, but I had to go with this one by @Blckknght the 'file.read()' that then permits me to open the out_file in 'w' mode is awesome! analyze and utilize did in fact convert to their English versions, I was just brain fried. I tried this script with a larger file that I needed to convert, and 1 issues is that "entire" was converted to "entyre". This because "tire : tyre" is in the dictionary and a partial match occured. Is there away to stop that, and keep it word for word?

Comment: Regarding `entire`, I think you'd need to switch to using regular expressions to fix that. It would be much easier if you reversed the dictionary of words, so that you could quickly check if an American English word word had an alternative spelling. I'll update my answer with a fix in a bit.

Comment: There will still be an issue with punctuation.  `re` is the best bet here.  Still, reverse the dictionary.  ;)

Comment: @Darren: OK, my edit is up. I've commented out the bits that rely on external files or modules, but you can plug in your (reversed) dictionary and data files instead of the examples I used, and it should work.

Comment: ok, dictionary is reversed :-)  regular expressions is new ground for me, I will begin my studies...

Comment: @EthanFurman: The regexp pattern I used, `r'\b\w+\b'` ignores non-alphanumeric characters. The `\b`s match word breaks.

Comment: @Blckknght - thanks so much - it is working like a dream now. I will have to study the script a bit to really understand every piece of the code. I just started reading about regular expressions for python, already amazed by how much you can do with them, with just the little i have read! Thanks again

Comment: @Blckknght - I have been studying up what I did not understand in your new code. I now understand `r'\b\w\b'`, the `.get()` method for dictionaries, and the `.group()` and `re.sub()` methods of regex - phew! What I am puzzled by is `def replacer(match):`, because this is a sub def of `def replacer_factory(spelling_dict):`, what argument is actually getting passed to the `(match)` in `def replacer(match):`?

Comment: The replacer function is passed as an argument to `re.sub`. `re.sub` will call it once for each word the regex pattern matches. The `match` argument will be a [`MatchObject`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) that is created by the `re` code to describe what was matched. It is the same kind of object that is returned by `re.search`.

Comment: @Blckknght - Thanks - with a little more study yesterday I have 98% figured out what is going on and in what order. 1 last question to finally clear it up for me. Does the `re.sub' function innately iterate through the text that is passed to it as the 3rd argument? In other words is it working like the `findall' command, rather than the `search' command that stops after finding the first match?

Comment: @Darren: Yes, `re.sub` runs through the entire text, replacing each match with whatever you want. To further complicate things, the second argument can work in several ways: it can be either a function taking a `MatchObject` (which will be called for each match) or a string (which can contain backreferences).

Comment: @Blckknght: I see, makes sense now that I know `re.sub` finds _all_ pattern matches in order. I am still baffled how the `matchobject` gets passed as the argument to the `def replacer(match)`? I can clearly see how the `text` is passed as the argument for `print(ame_to_bre(text)`, and I can clearly see how the `ame_to_bre_spellings` dictionary gets passed as the argument for `def replacer_factory(spelling_dict):`, but how **and** when the `matchobject` gets passed to `def replacer(match)` is the final piece of this puzzle that escapes me.

Comment: That happens inside of `re.sub`, which is why you can't see it. A reference to the `replacer` function is passed to `re.sub`, and its code (which is probably written in C) calls it for each match, passing in the `match` object as an argument.

Comment: @Blckknght: Thanks, at least knowing it is somewhat implicit, and that it just does what it does, I can keep that in mind for writing new code using the `re.sub` - cheers. I am that little bit python smarter for having studied this code :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `print` statement adds a newline of its own, but your lines already have their own newlines.  You can either strip the newline from your `new_line`, or use the lower-level

```
output.write(new_line)
```

instead (which writes **exactly** what you pass to it).

For your second question, I think we need an actual example.  `replace()` should indeed replace all occurrences.

```
>>> "abc abc abcd ab".replace("abc", "def")
'def def defd ab'
```

I'm not sure what your third question is asking.  If you want to replace the output file, do

```
output = open('output_test_file.txt', 'w')
```

`'w'` means you're opening the file for writing.

Comment: @ Tim Peters - thanks. I was confused, and '.replace' method does actually replace all instances. My brain was fried! For the 'w' or 'a' thing, I had to go with append because it is within a loop, and didn't work 'w'. Was just wondering if there is a way to use 'w' so that I don't have to been concerned if there is already data in the file or not. I can just overwrite it.

Answer (score 2):

As all the good answers above, I wrote a new version which I think is more pythonic, wish this helps:

```
# imported dictionary contains 1800 english:american spelling key:value pairs.
mydict = {
    'color': 'colour',
}


def replace_all(text, mydict):
    for english, american in mydict.iteritems():
        text = text.replace(american, english)
    return text

try:
    with open('new_output.txt', 'w') as new_file:
        with open('test_file.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                new_line = replace_all(line, mydict)
                new_file.write(new_line)
except:
    print "Can't open file!"
```

Also you can see the answer I asked before, it contains many best practice advices:
[Loading large file (25k entries) into dict is slow in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168349/loading-large-file-25k-entries-into-dict-is-slow-in-python)

Here is a few other tips about how to write python more python:)
http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

Good luck:)

Comment: thanks @shengy this is a great answer too, and useful links, much appreciated :-)