# Python Docs Wrong About Regular Expression "\b"?

Tags: python, regex

As a result of getting help with a question I had yesterday - [Python 2.7 - find and replace from text file, using dictionary, to new text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840640/python-2-7-find-and-replace-from-text-file-using-dictionary-to-new-text-file)  - I started learning regular expressions today to understand the regular expressions code that @Blckknght had kindly created for me in his answer.

However, it seems to me that the python docs (or more likely me) is slightly incorrect regarding the `\b` code. The section I am referring to in the python docs regarding \b is this:

> For example, r'\bfoo\b' matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'.

(Link to the page http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html )

I cannot understand how `'bar foo baz'` is a match? For example, if I create this code:

```
import re

m = re.search(r'\bfoo\b', 'bar foo baz')
m.group()
```

...then I get this result from the console:

```
'foo'
```

... and not

```
'bar foo baz'
```

In fact based on the rest of the explanation about '\b' in the python docs, I would actually expect `'foo'` to print to the console since it matches the empty string at the beginning and the end of a word.

So, what is the deal in the python docs that `'bar foo baz'` is a match?

Edit: I am using python 2.7

Comment: The word "matches" in the quote above means "matches some part of".  So `r'\bfoo\b'` matches the word `foo` but not the other parts of the string in both `'foo.'` and `'bar foo baz'`.

Comment: I think it makes more sense with the previous statements from the documentation included. e.g. `.. Note that formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa), ..`

Comment: @torek - thanks I see now. They are explaining how 'foo' is a match within the context of 'bar foo baz' and not that it is an exact match of 'bar foo baz'. Great that cleared it up for me!

Comment: @torek: you should make your comment an answer! =D

Comment: Yeah, `\bfoo\b` matches `foo`, `a foo b`, `a foo`, and `foo b`... but not `afoob`, `afoo b`, `a foob`, etc.

Comment: As you see, now you have two problems ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I would actually expect 'foo' to print to the console since it matches the empty string at the beginning and the end of a word.

Did you mean to write `' foo '`, with space on each end? It doesn't capture the spaces because `\b` matches *transitions*, gaps **between** characters, not characters themselves.

---

### Some ramblings on the way regex works

The regex system treats strings like a stream of "tokens", where there is **not** a 1:1 relationship between a token and a character in a text-file. Expressions like `\bfoo\b` are simply a super short way to write rules for a Pac-Man-like robot which travels along eating things.

For example, suppose we have `foo b4r b@z`. The token-stream might be something like:

```
misc    :  start_of_string
misc    :  word_boundary
letter  :  'f'
letter  :  'o'
letter  :  'o'
misc    :  word_boundary
wspace  :  ' '
misc    :  word_boundary
letter  :  'b'
number  :  '4'
letter  :  'r'
misc    :  word_boundary
wspace  :  ' '
misc    :  word_boundary
letter  :  'b'
misc    :  word_boundary
char    :  '@'
misc    :  word_boundary
letter  :  'z'
misc    :  word_boundary
misc    :  end_of_string
```

When you do `re.search(r'\bfoo\b',str)`, that *eventually* becomes a set of rules for pac-man to follow, roughly like:

1. Start at the beginning.
2. Ignore things until you find a `misc:word_boundary`.
3. Eat the `misc:word_boundary` and remember your current position as $N.
4. Try to eat a `letter:'f'`. If you can't, spit everything up, travel to $N+1, and go to rule #2.
5. Try to eat a `letter:'o'`. If you can't, spit everything up, travel to $N+1, and go to rule #2.
6. Try to eat a `letter:'o'`. If you can't, spit everything up, travel to $N+1, and go to rule #2.
7. Try to eat a `misc:'word_boundary'`. If you can't, spit everything up, travel to $N+1, and go to rule #2.
8. Tell me what's in your stomach now.

Obviously there's a lot more complexity you can layer on there, such as with loops (`+*?`) and shorthand (like `\w` for "`a` or `b` or `c` or ...") or how it selectively ignores some tokens, but hopefully the basic style is revealed.

### So... can I parse HTML/XML now?

Short answer? No. Pac-man only operates on lines of stuff, but XML is like a tree. Pac-man would have to stop at certain points and hire some pac-men to explore for him (with their own *different* set of rules) and report back. Those sub-contractors would have sub-sub-contractors of their own too...

Anyway, Pac-man's people-skills are stunted after living in an inescapable maze full of deadly ghosts and performance-enhancing drugs. You can't get very far in a Pac-Corp when all you can say is Wakka.

Comment: now I get it even more. I was still left with the question - what is the difference between `\s` and `\b`. And now I understand.

Comment: No, I didn't mean to put a space at the front of ` foo`

Comment: And thanks again - you keep updating your explanation and it just keeps getting better. Now I feel totally educated about `\b` !

Comment: +1 for pacman analogy.  Very useful teaching technique.  Well done.

Comment: While this is a really good answer overall, it's got an (minor) error in it. There are no word boundaries inside of the string `'b33z'`, since the "word characters" (`\w`) include both letters and numbers. A regexp like `'r\b\w+\b'` will match the whole thing.

Comment: @Blckknght Sorry, had a brainfart editing that in about 20 minutes earlier: I wanted a `\b` example that wasn't just letter-to-whitespace.

Comment: @Darien: Ah, I understand. How about `'b@z'`?